# ReactJS setState with object and array

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to have a data structure in terms of array
e.g.

```
data[0]
  title:"ABC"
  photo: "./123.jpg"
  summ: "text text test"
data[1]
  title:"ABCD"
  photo: "./1234.jpg"
  summ: "text texwt test"
```

I have attempted to setState like this, but it won't work.
Please guide me ;(

```
             this.setState({
               data:{
                title: [ ...this.state.data.title, title ],
                photo: [ ...this.state.data.photo, photo ],
                summ: [ ...this.state.data.summ, summ ]   

                    }

                  });
```

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.state.data.concat is not a function

[image]

/////
Mistake on not initialize my state

```
// this is incorrect
this.state={
data:{
title:null,
photo:null,
summ:null,
}
//The correct version is
this.state={
data:[],
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't work` ?

Comment: You are somehow creating an object of arrays whereas you want and array of objects. You seem to want something more in the line of `this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, {title, photo, summ}]})`

Comment: You said you want data to be an array. However, in `setState`, you are assigning data to an object

Comment: Don't give us an "e.g." of your data, show us a real definition in JavaScript.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.state.data.concat is not a function
@FelixKling

Comment: The data is Json data, I want to store it into a state variable
@crashmstr

Comment: You have to adapt it to your actual use case of course. Without a complete example we cannot give you a complete solution.

Comment: I have a json data., the json data structure is shown in the example
I want it to store in the this.state.data
this variable is empty at first.
how would you save data into this.state.data ?
@FelixKling

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as initializing `data` with an empty array. But again, without a complete example it's hard to provide a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felix Kling said in commentary, you want an Array of Object so you need to have a structure like that :

```js
this.setState({
  data: [
    ...this.state.data,
    { title, photo, summ }
  ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.state.data.concat is not a function

Comment: How did you initialize your state ? Try to put this in the constructor : this.state = { data: [] }

Answer (score 1):

The reason your solution doesn't work is that you are trying to assign an object to an array.

I am not sure if you are trying to add an item to array or change single item from an array. If you are trying to add, you can do it like this:

```
this.setState({
...this.state.data, {title, photo, summ}
})
```

However if you are trying to change an item from the array. You should store in a temporary variable and then assign it like this.

```
const tempArray = this.state.data;
this.setState({
    data: tempArray.filter(//some change function)
})
```

If you are trying to initialize your data into state, you can do it like this:

```
import JsonData from "./myJsonData"
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.searchBarRef = React.createRef();
this.state = {
  data: JsonData
};
```

}

Hope this solves your issue. If I couldn't explain clearly please say, so I can try to give a better answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have a Json data, I want to use store it into a state variable and display it later
provided I have two buttons A and B. 
A will show list A // $filter column eq 1
B will show list B // $first column eq 2
I am trying to save the data into state so when I click the button,
the query is chanaged and data will be changed too

Comment: I update my answer and added how to initialize state with jsonData. @RandomI.T